# EC2 IAM Policy not working with ResourceTag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["ec2:Describe*", "ec2:CreateSnapshot"],
"Condition": {
       "StringEquals": {
         "ec2:ResourceTag/test":"true"
       }
},
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"

    }
  ]
}
```

This is the IAM policy I am using. If I take out the condition line it works fine so it's just down to that. I tagged the instance with the tag key "test" and set the value to "true". What am I doing incorrectly? I am using the ec2 api tools and using `ec2-describe-volumes` to test

Answer (score 8):

Not all EC2 actions allow resource-level permissions.  Neither the Describe* actions nor CreateSnapshot are supported currently.

This lists the actions for EC2 that support resource-level permissions.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I've just been chasing exactly this myself!

Comment: I believe, based on this link, the answer may no longer be true: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html